# Where are the photos taken with my app stored?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, photolibrary

Besides browsing the Photolibrary I've enabled the Camera to add a photo to my

```
    @IBAction func startCameraButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let startCameraController = UIImagePickerController()
    startCameraController.delegate = self
    startCameraController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
    startCameraController.allowsEditing = true

    self.presentViewController(startCameraController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    //invoiceImageHolder.image!.scaleAndRotateImage2(280)
    //self.invoiceImageHolder.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((180.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)) / 180.0)

}
```

Every user input can be deleted, but now I'd like to know where the corresponding photo is. When I browse the photo library I can't see the photos taken with my app? Where are those photos stored?

[edit]
This is my saveImage process

```
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    saveImage(selectedImage, path: fileInDocumentsDirectory("\(uniqueImageName)"))
    // set the unique image reference in textfield

    // Set photoImageView to display the selected image
    self.invoiceImageHolder.image = selectedImage

    // Dismiss the picker
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}

    func saveImage(image: UIImage, path: String) -> Bool{
    let pngImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    //        let jpgImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
    let result = pngImageData?.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
    //print("Save result \(result)")
    return result!
}
```

EDIT hmm I think I see where the photos are stored, but now how do I browse to them for deletions?

I think it's here:

> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CBFE9E9D-A657-4011-8B9F-EF0C9BB2C603/Documents/

BUT everytime i restart the app the part between Application and /Documents is different??

[image]

Still not a working solution, but for those newbies as me this is a valuable readup: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Directories_in_Swift_on_iOS_8

[EDIT 2]
with this code i am able to see all whiles stored with my app. I was a bit surprise to see all the files

```
        // Files stored in my app filemanager

    let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    do {
        print("Start filemanager")
        let filelist = try  filemgr.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(documentsDirectory())
        for filename in filelist {
            print(filename)
        }
    } catch {
        print("No directory path \(error)")
    }
    // end filemanager
```

Answer (score 1):

`UIImagePickerController()` doesn't automatically save your photos into the library. See its `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` protocol and you'll see that it has a method returning your `UIImage` after making a photo. Then you can save it:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: i am aware i edit my question with more save image process function

Answer (score 0):

you save them - not in the photo library - but as 'simply' files inside your app's documents folder. There is no standard UI for deletion then.

You need to write your own ViewController to show & handle deletions then.

Comment: hmm didn't realise that. Is it correct that the id of my app (the part between Application and Documents) is always different? I don't see how i can get inside my app's documents folder, if that is the case.
When i delete my app from my phone are all the files in folder Documents also deleted???

Comment: Yes and yes. The alert shown by iOS states this clearly: ‘Deleting “app name” will also delete all of its data.’